# How to get current group size after filtering charts

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have 2 charts. On filtering of the 2nd chart, how can I get the filtered `firstchartGroup` size like filtered `firstchartDim`?

I tried

```
chart2.on("filtered",function(chart)
{
    console.log(firstchartDim.top(Infinity).length);//including filters
    console.log(firstchartGroup.size());//independent of filters

});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossfilter won't remove bins when they become empty, so you have to manually ignore the zeros when you're counting the bins. Here's one way to do this, [adapted from the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins):

```
console.log(firstchartGroup.all().filter(function(d) { return d.value != 0; }).length);
```